# Regex in nginx inside map

Tags: nginx

I cannot fix routing in nginx for different parts in URI . So if the request has URI starting with `de` it should pass the traffic to `app_b`. That does not happen and I'm getting error: `invalid URL prefix in "http://"`

Here's the config.

```
map $request_uri $resources_location {
    "/"  "app_a:1234/";
    "^.*de.*$"  "app_b:2345/";
}


server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;


        proxy_pass http://$resources_location;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~ ^/(assets|public|favicon.ico) {
        proxy_pass http://$resources_location;
    }
}
```

How that can be solved (also with a help of map)?

Comment: I think the problem would be simplified by using two server blocks.

Comment: You do not specify a default for your map, so if neither line matches the empty string is returned. Also, that second line is missing the `~` operator to indicate a regular expression. See the [map directive documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).